# Can I define an input's attributes based on object properties?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Imagine I have the following object:

```
inputAttributes: {
    type: "range",
    name: "range",
    min: 0,
    max: 100,
}
```

and I want to create the following input:

```
const RangeInput = (props) => {
    return (
        <input
            type="range"
            name="range"
            min="0"
            max="100"
        />
    );
};

export default RangeInput;
```

Is it possible to somehow loop over the the key-value pairs of the object and apply them to the input as properties? This is inside a React component.

Comment: You can use `<input {...obj.inputAttributes} />` as seen in the dupe

Comment: @NickParsons Thanks, that's useful! Put it as an answer so I can select it as the right one!

Comment: No worries. As this is a duplicate of another question, your question has been closed so answers here can't be posted